# How can I specify type annotations in Dart with `combineReducers`?

Tags: dart, flutter

I receive a message at the `List` from linter saying:

> Specify type annotations

However I can't understand what type it wants. For `Map` I could get like so:

`<String, String>{}`

Where my `Map` is at the end, and I specify the type at the beginning, but I can't find the correct type for my reducer and my epics.

My current code:

```dart
final profileReducer = combineReducers<Profile>([
  TypedReducer<Profile, UpdateProfileBalanceAction>(_updateProfileBalance),
  TypedReducer<Profile, FetchProfileResultAction>(_setProfile),
]);
```

and:

```dart
final epics = combineEpics<AppState>([
  TypedEpic<AppState, FetchProfileAction>(profileEpic),
]);
```

Comment: Dart doesn't support union type, so you can't have the _real_ type here. A dynamic will be required

Comment: :( that means I just can't fix that warning? (I tried using `dynamic`, and didn't work)

Comment: That means you cannot have a mistake-proof type. But you can fix the warning. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type I needed to use was:

```dart
final Function profileReducer = combineReducers<Profile>(
<Profile Function(Profile, dynamic)>[
  TypedReducer<Profile, FetchProfileResultAction>(_setProfile),
]);
```

But to make that more usable, I created a type:

```dart
import 'package:utgard/store/models/profile.dart';

typedef ProfileReducers = Profile Function(Profile, dynamic);
```

Then I can use in my reducers, like so:

```dart
final Function profileReducer = combineReducers<Profile>(<ProfileReducers>[
  TypedReducer<Profile, FetchProfileResultAction>(_setProfile),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dart doesn't support union type so typing actions properly won't be possible.. A "less realistic type" will be required

You can do the following:

```
final profileReducer = combineReducers<Profile>(<TypedReducer<Profile, Action>>[
  TypedReducer<Profile, UpdateProfileBalanceAction>(_updateProfileBalance),
  TypedReducer<Profile, FetchProfileResultAction>(_setProfile),
]);
```

Comment: I already tried that, however I get the following error: `The argument type 'List<TypedReducer<Profile, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<(Profile, dynamic) → Profile>'.`

Comment: Ah, `combineReducers` takes a function directly. `TypedReducer` do not work

Comment: That's ok! I've found the answer, and posted here, thanks anyway!